# Check if a string is a subset in another string in R

Tags: r, string, subset

I've this data below that includes `ID`, and `Code` (chr type)

[image]

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3, 4, 4)
Code <- c("0011100000", "0001100000", "1001100000", "1100000000", 
          "1000000000", "1000000000", "0100000000", "0010000000", "0010000001", "0010000001")
df <- data.frame(ID, Code)
```

I need to remove records (within each ID) based `Code` value pattern, That is:

For each `ID`, we look at the values of `Code`, and we remove the ones that are subset of other row.

For example, for `ID`=1, row #2 is a subset of row #1, so we remove row #2. But, row #3 is NOT a subset of row #2 or #3, so we keep it.

For `ID`=2, row #5 is a subset of row #4, so we remove it.

For `ID`=3, they are all different, so we keep them all.

For `ID`=4, since the `Code` for both records are the same, then keep the first one.

Here is the expected final view of the results:

[image]

Comment: I imagine this will be pretty computationally intensive. You have to compare each row with all other rows in each group to find out if it's duplicated.

Comment: The data set I'm dealing with is not too big. So I'm not too worried about memory issues.

Comment: What makes a value a subset of another? Why is row #2 a subset of row #1?

Comment: Say, if you remove all leading and tail 0's, you will end up with 111 for row #1 and 11 for row #2, and 11 is in 111. However, comparing row #1 and row #3, 111 is not in 10011 (or vice versa). So, both values and position of the string matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that pretty, but a bit of checking of every combination with a join will do it.

Convert to a *data.table*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

Make a row counter, and identify all the `1` locations in each string and save to a list.

```
df[, rn := .I]
df[, ones := gregexpr("1", df$Code)]
```

Join each group to itself, and compare the lists where the row numbers don't match. Then keep the row numbers where the lists are subsets, and drop these rows from the original data. In the case of duplicates, only remove the first occasion of the duplicate.

```
df[
  funion(
    df[df, on=c("ID","rn>rn"), if(all(i.ones[[1]] %in% ones[[1]])) .(Code=i.Code), by=.EACHI][, -"rn"],
    df[df, on=c("ID","rn<rn"), if(all(i.ones[[1]] %in% ones[[1]])) .(Code=i.Code), by=.EACHI][, -"rn"]
  ),
  on=c("ID","Code"),
  mult="first",
  drop := 1
]
df[is.na(drop), -c("rn","ones","drop")]


#   ID       Code
#1:  1 0011100000
#2:  1 1001100000
#3:  2 1100000000
#4:  3 1000000000
#5:  3 0100000000
#6:  3 0010000000
#7:  4 0010000001
```

Comment: Thanks so much! One questions: if for one ID, both Code are the same, which one is going to get picked here?

Comment: I noticed that if an ID have the same code, then it excludes both of them. I edited the question and added ID=4.

Comment: @user9292 - see my update - this should address the duplicate issue.